# How can I use different background images for different pages in a multipage form using Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I'm using the webform module with page breaks to display a large form. I would like to have different images for the background of each of these different form pages. Does anyone have a suggestion for how I could do this in Drupal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does each page of the form have a wrapping HTML element with a unique ID? You could just use that ID to set the background image in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out two ways to solve this. The first way was to use javascript to detect some pre-defined element on the page and based on the attributes of that element, add the background-image css to the div. The second way, and admittedly more drupal-like, is to add a preprocess function to the template.php file that accesses the form page number and puts a div around it with the number in it. Then you can just style that div. Thanks!